# Jersey2 é diferente de Jersey v2.x?

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

Estou tentando implementar Swagger no Jersey e existe a implementação para ambos os Jerseys. Querisa saber se Jersey2 é diferente de Jersey v2.x? ou é a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey (ou JAX-RS) é uma dependência que auxilia na implementação de servidores RESTful em Java. Essa dependência possui duas versões macros, Jersey1 (ou simplesmente Jersey) e Jersey2, no caso o 1.x ou 2.x indica que seria compatível com qualquer uma delas, sendo assim:

1.x indica que é compatível com 1.1/1.1.1/1.2/1.2.1/etc
2.x indica que é compatível com 2.1/2.1.1/2.2/2.2.1/etc

Lembrando que algumas coisas das versões 1.x podem não ser compatíveis nas versões 2.x e vice versa.